# AVCaptureSession didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL: not called when interruption (e.g. control center) occurs

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I sunk a ton of time into this so I thought I'd repost.

I am using AVCaptureSession with AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to allow users to record video while providing a pause recording button.

This works great until the app is backgrounded, the control center is lifted, or an interruption such as alarm/call occurs. Depending on the device hardware, we see a different kind of bug.

- On older devices, the capture session will fail to start recording after such an event, even if we re-initialize the captureSession.
- On newer devices, the existing video, if it exists, will be fine, but any subsequent attempts to resume recording will either fail outright, or fail to record audio.

In the first situation, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL: will never get called. In the second situation, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL: will be called, but didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL: will not.

Currently, we are doing this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [self initializeCaptureSessionAndOutputData]; //based on your requirements
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [self.captureSession startRunning];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(interruptionDidOccur)
                                               name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   [self.captureSession stopRunning];
   [[NSNotificationCenter] defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)interruptionDidOccur {
   [self.movieFileOutput stopRecording]; //expect didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL to be called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is undocumented, but solvable. In addition to calling

`[self.captureSession stopRunning]`

in viewWillDisappear: it must be called whenever a UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification notification is fired too. Here is the sample code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self handleAppReturn];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(becameActive)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(resignActive)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)resignActive {
    [self.videoCameraManager.captureSession stopRunning];
    if (!self.isPaused) {
       [self pauseVideo];
    }
}

- (void)becameActive {
    [self.videoCameraManager.captureSession startRunning];
}
```